# Is it possible to use javascript instead of java in such conditions?

Tags: javascript, java

I made up desktop application using java few years ago. It is no problem to use until now, but these day I think it's better way to run web application than desktop, for some reasons. anyway, I use some objects in java desktop application, for example...

BufferedReader, DataOutputStream, InputStreamReader, OutputStreamWriter, 
PrintWriter, HttpUrlConnection ....

Do javascript have such objects supporting similar fucntions...? I'm afraid to they don't have it. I'm just newbie on this, It is just a hobby. so I don't know much about it. but I heard these day's hottest language is javascript, so I just want to jump to javascript...so please help me if you know about something. thanks.

Comment: despite the names being similar, there's no connection between the two languages.

Comment: Off topic quesion. BTW, Java is high level programming language and javascript is scripting language. You cannot compare Java and javascript.

Comment: A desktop application run on your computer, and has access to the file system, so you can read and write files. A web application run on the server, with some script (JavaScript) running in the browser, to allow client-side *behavior*, and it does not have access to the file system. So no, JavaScript does not have reader/writer/stream classes.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks your comment. if I remove code about accessing file system, can I do it? What do you think about HttpUrlConnection to using proxy, setRequestProperty...etc.

Comment: About file is not main fucntion. the main is http network... not big file. just small text lines, main functions are http post and get...login some site, and write document, parsing text data, etc.

Comment: The web browser version of `HttpUrlConnection` is [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/).

Comment: Have a look at http://nwjs.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the default JavaScript language doesn't allow reading and writing to files the program node.js is designed to act as a server side JavaScript and does allow reading and writing of files along with a broad npm library to add different functionalities. 
More information on the [nodejs web site](http://nodejs.org)

Comment: Thanks your comment. What do you think about HttpUrlConection? Using proxy servers, Sending Http Request, and Getting respose code, and also parsing some text data, etc.

Comment: It supports http requests and has all the functionality of the JavaScript language for parsing and editing. Responses and requests can often be handled by APIs that support such and possibly other methods. I haven't spent much time on all aspects but a detailed description can be found on the node js Api documentation nodejs.org/api

Comment: And nodejs is capable of being a proxy not only simply using them